# JavaScript Replace in Class

Tags: javascript

I need to remove a period inside of a div that only has a class attribute (no id -- system generated page).

```
<div class="myClass">
Some text . 
</div>
```

I need to remove the period. How can this be accomplished using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

Without jQuery, here is the old-school option:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i=0,len=divs.length;i<len;++i){
  if (/(?:^|\s)myClass(?:\s|$)/.test(divs[i].className)){
    // Removes every period
    divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML.replace( /\./g, '' );
  }
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$('div.myClass').html(function(i,oldHTML){
  return oldHTML.replace( /\./g, '' );
});
```

Comment: What about `document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')`?

Comment: @Rocket Or `document.querySelectorAll()`; both of these are not 'old-school', having been implemented only in newer browsers.

Comment: All good until you do a string replace on `innerHTML`, which has all kinds of potential problems if the `<div>` contains other elements.

Comment: @TimDown I agree in principle, but not with "all kinds of potential problems". a) The OP's example is pretty simple and clear; b) the only problems I can think of are 1. removing and re-adding elements will remove procedurally-bound event handlers, or 2. pulling out periods inside of attributes (changing names or classes). That's exceptionally unlikely to be a problem for this user, or most anyone who would need this odd JS-only hack.

Comment: Those were the two I had in mind also, so maybe I overstated it slightly. I think you're right that it's likely to be safe for this particular case, but I think doing string manipulation on `innerHTML` is generally dangerous, is used blindly by many developers and I'd prefer to see warnings when it's being encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(".myClass").html(function(i, html) { return html.replace(/\.$/, ""); });
```

Comment: It's not efficient to perform the query twice. You should either use the function form of `html()` (as in my answer) or `var a = $('...'); a.html(a.html().replace(...));`

Comment: Ah, I had no idea it had a function form! The more you know, thanks :)